# Como puedo hacer este SELECT SQL para una Base de datos

Tags: sql

No consigo hacer el siguiente SELECT, quiero mostrar el origen, destino y el precio del billete de la tabla billete pero en lugar de que en la columna de origen y destino salgan 1, 2, 3 o 4 (Que son los id de cada ciudad) quiero que me muestre el origen el nombre de la ciudad y en el destino también el nombre, algo así;

```
ORIGEN  DESTINO  PRECIO
MADRID  VALENCIA  50
```

De esta forma con todos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es MySQL? Recuerda indicar siempre en tus preguntas, en qué motor quieres hacer tus consultas.

Comment: Sí, gracias! lo tendré en cuenta!

Comment: lo que quieres será esto select c.nombre origen, c2.nombre destino, b.precio from billete b join ciudad c on b.origen = c.id left join ciudad c2 on b.destino=c2.id order by cliente

Comment: lo que quieres será esto select c.nombre origen, c2.nombre destino, b.precio from billete b join ciudad c on b.origen = c.id left join ciudad c2 on b.destino=c2.id order by cliente

Comment: Pon la consulta que tienes hasta ahora y aclara la relación entre las tablas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es realmente consultar 2 valores en otra tabla, lo que tienes que hacer practicamente es hacer los joins necesarios como que si estuvieras buscando en 2 tablas distintas (aunque no sea el caso) pero el sql lo interpreta de esta forma en el ejemplo que puse en el comentario lo hice de esa forma.

```
select 
  c.nombre_ciudad origen, 
  c2.nombre_ciudad destino, 
  b.precio 
from 
  billete b 
join ciudad c 
  on b.origen = c.id 
Join ciudad c2 
  on b.destino=c2.id 
order by 
  cliente asc
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mau, ha sido de gran ayuda! Lo que no acabo de entender es la parte del left join como trabaja, es decir, es como si te salieras del join en el que estabas e hicieras otro join para c2 en este caso?

Comment: Tal vez podrías marcar la respuesta como positiva para que sirva a futuras preguntas.

Comment: Sí, justo lo acabo de hacer, gracias!

Comment: @Ewejnoj un left join te traerá todos los registros de ambas tablas, incluso aquellos de la izquierda que no tengan registros asociados en la tabla de la derecha

Comment: @BetaM? No lo he hecho en las que no me funcionan 